# Creating an invite in the current channel of Discord.js v13

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create an invite when a user sends a command. This used to work fine in v12 of Discord.js, but seems to not work anymore for v13.

I've looked through the documentation and I'm having serious trouble finding how to do this in the new version. Right now I'm getting an error (I'm using Typescript) that says the following:

> Property 'createInvite' does not exist on type 'DMChannel | PartialDMChannel | NewsChannel | TextChannel | ThreadChannel | VoiceChannel'

How would you be able to a create an invite in the current channel in v13 of DiscordJS?

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return

    if (message.content == `${prefix}setinvite`) {
        let guildId = message.guild?.id
        let invite = message.channel.createInvite({}) // error
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`createInvite`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=createInvite) function doesn't exist on all channel types, which is what typescript is picking up on.

To resolve this issue I suggest checking the [channel type](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=type) before attempting to execute the function.

Example:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return

    if (message.content == `${prefix}setinvite` && message.channel.type === "text") {
        let guildId = message.guild?.id
        let invite = message.channel.createInvite({})
    }
});
```